# Flutter web Auth can't access query parameter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, discord

I'm trying to use Discord OAuth API and I'm using [this_package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth), it works with other APIs such as Google & Facebook but I can't access the values in the URL after redirecting to localhost. Am i doing something wrong? or is there another way to use Discord OAuth?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_auth/flutter_web_auth.dart';

class DiscordLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DiscordLoginState createState() => _DiscordLoginState();
}

class _DiscordLoginState extends State<DiscordLogin> {

  void discordAuth()async{
    String discordAuthUrl = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[MY_DISCORD_APP_CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Fapi%2Fdiscord&response_type=code&scope=identify%20email";
    String callBackUrlScheme = "127.0.0.1";
    final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(url: discordAuthUrl, callbackUrlScheme: callBackUrlScheme);
    final token = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters['code'];
    print(token);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child : Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text(
                'login'
              ),
            ),
                onPressed: discordAuth,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please let me know if you need me to change anything, thanks!